# How DRY build 2 different webpack bundles from same component

Tags: reactjs, webpack

i have React component(Foo) with many components inside and complex logic.
This component used as root component for two routes. One route - guest side, second - user side.
When Foo used in user part, component use heavy library(build in separate file).

Have some way build two different bundles from Foo. First for guest, without require heavy library, second - with lib.